# Migrate documents from SQL Server to SharePoint document library with the meta data?

Tags: sql

I'm new in SharePoint and I have a requirement to migrate millions of documents stored as BLOB's in SQL Server to a new SharePoint Document library. Can you suggest the best approaches for the same?